# Is there a single word or phrase for "logical thinking capacity"?

Tags: single-word-request, phrase-request

Is there a single word or phrase in Korean that means logical thinking capacity?

For example, I could like to say "He has a strong capacity of logical thinking"

___이 강하다.

Comment: I have submitted an edit that includes "phrase" in your question as I don't think there is a single word. Also, it would be nicer if you could include an example of "logical thinking capacity" in your question. If you don't like my edit, you can always roll it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that "[사고력(思考力)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=19029500)" can be a candidate. To be more precise, "[논리적(論理的)](http://krdic.naver.com/detail.nhn?docid=7770101)" can be added.

> - 이 과목은 아이들에게 창조적이고 종합적인 사고력을 키워 주는 것이 그 목적이다.
> - 여옥은 학교 시절 무척 총명했으며 명희보다 적극적이었고 사고력도 명쾌했다.

Comment: Looks like the first example sentence is "논리적인 사고력을 기르다". What other types of 사고력 can there be?

Comment: @user17915 For example, "창의적 사고력", "종합적 사고력", "비판적 사고력" and "[대안적 문제 해결 사고력](http://terms.naver.com/entry.nhn?docId=383489&cid=50306&categoryId=50306)", etc.

Comment: I agree that "사고력" is a good candidate!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest "논리적 사고력".

논리 is 'logic' and 적 is a suffix that changes a noun to an adjective.

사고력 is 'ability to think'.

It literally means "ability to think logically".

Comment: While this definitely does mean "logical thinking capacity," it may *technically* go against what @user17915 was looking for. In both the question title and body, he asks, "Is there a single word?" - I think he was looking to *avoid* using an adjective.

Comment: @dotVezz I edited the question and the OP accepted my edit.

Comment: Yep, now it works.